# Cancel Entry Update / Display Error using EE3 Extension Hook

Tags: channel-entries, channel, extension, ee3, hook

I am using a 'Channel Entry Model Extension Hook' in EE3 to allow me to carry out further validation of a selection of fields.

This is working fine, currently with the 'before_channel_entry_update' hook.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/model/channel-entry/index.html#before-channel-entry-update

However, If the validation fails, I am unable to cancel the 'update' to the entry.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can:

1. Cancel the update
2. Display an error message of my choice